# materialize modal not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I dont understand why modal is not working:

```
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i class="material-icons icn_profile waves-effect">person</i>
</a>
 <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I try many solution like put the modal div outside the header section, and vary jquery script like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
   $('.modal').modal();
 });
$(document).ready(function(){
   // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
   $('#modal1').modal('open');
 });
```

and more..
I can not be able to reach the solution here on stack overflow. I have also loaded jquery library before materialize.js at the end of the body section. The js console doesn't show any error.
thanks

Comment: How about learn to make modal? It's easy and more flexible. https://youtu.be/vbBvNx_rVmU 
I'm not push you. I just recommend.

Answer (score 1):

There could be an error with the sequence of the scripts that you are bringing to your HTML.

**NOTE:** Since I don't know the relative paths of your css and js files, I gave them myself. Make sure to give them the correct path. Make sure that they are loaded on correctly to your DOM.

See if the following works for you.

```
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i class="material-icons icn_profile waves-effect">person</i></a>



   <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
   $('.modal').modal();

 });

    </script>
</body>
```

Please follow the order. **Jquery must come before materialize.js .** Otherwise your code seems to work fine.

If the error persists, please tell me.

**Also**, I would like to add that the following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
   $('#modal1').modal('open');
});
```

will open the modal as soon as the page opens. Do you really want that behavior? The code I posted above works fine; when you click on the **person icon** the **modal opens**. That's the intended behavior desired usually. But otherwise also, if you want the modal to open as soon as the page loads, that will work fine as well.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I kept trying until I got it. I don't know if this is what you want, but it works for me:

I have this in the header

```
declare let $: any;
```

after

```
     openit(){
      $('#modal1').modal('open');
}
```

and in my html

```
    <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" data-target="modal1" (click)="openit()">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal"materialize="modal" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your .js file:

```
//Modal trigger
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});
```